Aws Amplify init command fails with error - "invalid configuration settings", but no other information is provided
When I was trying to setup amplify in my android project in ubuntu, Android Studio, this error was coming when I try amplify init in project's root directory. But I was having a valid set of credentials. I was using AWS SSO for auth.

After I followed some issue trackers of AWS-Amplify, I learned about the temporary credentials that Amplify can use.
Previously I have set the AWS access key ID, AWS secret access key, and AWS session token in the ~/.aws/credentials file, and all the tools were working fine.
But AWS-Amplify init was not working with that and giving me an error -

Invalid configuration settings

Then I tried to set the credentials in Environment Variables as
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID= "key id"
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY= "secret key"
export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN= "session token"

and that worked smoothly. Aws Amplify looks for creds in Env. variables.
